# Data are erasing after filter it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

The problem is that if I am applying filter,  **filteredList** will be updated based on the filter if I would like to filter it again, it will give me nothing back.

```
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState([]);
  const [searchquery, setSearchquery] = useState("");


     useEffect(() => {
        fetch("api/device/getall")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              setIsLoaded(true);
              setFilteredList(result);
            },
            (error) => {
              setIsLoaded(true);
              setError(error);
            }
          );
      }, []);


 const FilterSearchQuery = (filteredData) => {
    const filteredDevice = filteredData.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.deviceName
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(searchquery.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
    );
    return filteredDevice;
  };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        var filteredData = FilterDevicelocation(filteredList);
        setFilteredList(filteredData);
      }, [searchquery]);
```

Comment: You could create a copy of `filteredList` so that you don't change the original data.

Comment: Also, I guess your question was downvoted because it's not very clear.

Comment: You are using functions in the code that aren't included. Also, it seems like some kind of rookie JavaScript question. That's why it's downvoted.

Comment: @NicholasObert, how must it be saved? Can you please give me one example of it? Many thanks

Comment: @Denis the `FilterSearchQuery` function shouldn't mutate the original data since it's basically a wrapper around the `Array.prototype.filter` method, which returns a shallow copy of the string. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The only place in your code where `filteredList` is mutated is when you invoke the `setFilteredList` hook.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasObert very much for explaining it is pretty hard to implement such staff first time in a real project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

Filtering an array is necessarily a reducing action. The issue is that you are reducing the state that is the "source of truth", and once reduced can never be un-reduced unless you fetch the entire state again. The issue is caused by the `useEffect` hook that filters and updates the `filteredList` state when the query value updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  var filteredData = FilterDevicelocation(filteredList);
  setFilteredList(filteredData); // <-- removed array entries
}, [searchquery]);
```

## Solution

`filteredList` is your "source of truth", don't mutate it once it is set. The filtered result you want to render is what is considered ***derived state***, meaning it is "state" that is easily derived from other state and/or props. In this case the filtered "state" is derived from the current `filteredList` state array and the current `searchQuery` string values. Do the filtering inline prior to rendering it.

Example:

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("api/device/getall")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      setList(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
    });
}, []);

const filteredList = useMemo(() => list.filter(
  (item) =>
    item.deviceName
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
), [list, searchQuery]);

// use the derived filteredList from here out
```

Comment: Hi @Drew many thanks for your response I am trying to implement this example into my project but I have just one question you define ```filteredList ```  as constant but what is supposed to do with  ```const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState([]);```

Comment: @Denis I renamed your `filteredList` to `list` since it is the full list, and created a new `filteredList` which is the memoized filtered list using `list` and `searchQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it but how to deal with the rest of the filters function the main idea of ```  setFilteredList(filteredData); ``` to store all filters every time then the user changes an option which must be depended to each over, many thanks !!!

Comment: @Denis Sorry if I've somehow failed to sufficiently explain the issue and solution. The entire idea is to ***not*** use `setFilteredData` at all so you aren't mutating your data source. Fetch it and leave it be (*unless the data is changing, i.e. add, remove, reorder, etc*). Use the `list` and `searchQuery` states to ***derive*** the "state" of a filtered list. Any time either `list` or `searchQuery` update, `filteredList` is recomputed. All the filtering is handled in the `list.filter(......)` used to compute `filteredList` in the `useMemo` hook callback.